# Issue sending arabic text notification

Tags: php, android, push-notification, arabic

I am sending notification from my app server.
When i am sending english text it s ok but when i send arabic words i got this:

[image]

This is my code :

```
<?php 
require "connection.php";

$title=$_POST['title'];
$message=$_POST['message'];

    function send_notification ($tokens, $message)
    {
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
        $fields = array(
             'registration_ids' => $tokens,
             'data'=>$message
            );
        $headers = array(
            'Authorization:key =MY_KEY',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
            );
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
       $result = curl_exec($ch);           
       if ($result === FALSE) {
           die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
       }
       curl_close($ch);
       return $result;
    }


    $sql = " Select fcm_token From fcm_info";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $tokens = array();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $tokens[] = $row["fcm_token"];
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    $message = array("message" => $message,"title" => $title);
    $message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message);
    echo $message_status;
 ?>
```

I have tried to update Content-type to :
'Content-Type: application/json; charset-utf8 '
and added JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE to json_encode()

But still getting result as the image above..
Any suggestions please.

UPDATED :
My notification.html file
[image]

**SOLUTION:**

Decode the htmlentities to characters by using this :

*html_entity_decode(json_encode($fields));*

Answer (score 0):

Replace the opening  with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Send Notification</title>
</head>
```

It tells the browser to use UTF-8 for encoding.